# Add drop down menu on button click - windows 8

Tags: button, drop-down-menu, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to display a `drop down menu` when a user clicks a `button`. Something like `comboBox` but instead of the comboBox its a button. How can I do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using PopupMenu. Here is the code for other's reference.

```
    public static Rect GetElementRect(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        GeneralTransform buttonTransform = element.TransformToVisual(null);
        Point point = buttonTransform.TransformPoint(new Point());
        return new Rect(point, new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menu = new PopupMenu();
        menu.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Label", (command) =>
        {
            //do work
        }));

        // We don't want to obscure content, so pass in a rectangle representing the sender of the context menu event.
        // We registered command callbacks; no need to handle the menu completion event
        var chosenCommand = await menu.ShowForSelectionAsync(GetElementRect((FrameworkElement)sender));
        if (chosenCommand == null) // The command is null if no command was invoked.
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Milan,

You'll need to create a custom control or a user control that combines a button and a popup. You could also just implement this in-place with a button and popup. I suggest you look at Callisto's Menu control and start from there to implement your dropdown menu: 
[Callisto controls (includes a Menu)](https://github.com/timheuer/Callisto)